# Finding the probability density function of Z=X+Y

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

I am stuck with finding the pdf for Z = X+Y, I have the pdf for X and Y.

The problem:

$f_Y(y) = 1/(b-a) ~~\big[25 \leqslant y \leqslant 35\big]$

$f_X(x) = 0.1 - 0.00667x+1.1\times 10^{-4} x^2$

I was trying to find the $\Pr(Z\geqslant z)$

I tried to solve it as following

$\Pr(Z \geqslant z) = 1 - \Pr(Z < z) = 1- Pr(X+Y<z) = 1- Pr(X< z - Y)$

as the problem is with sea level (X) and wave level (Y) I think they are independent

$\int f_Y(y)\times\int f_X(x) $

Is this true? or should I use double integral and if yes how?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You probably already know about [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020), but please try to improve the typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the density of $X+Y$ is $\int f_X(x-y)f_Y(y)\, dy$ provided $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Without independence it is not possible to find the distribution of $X+Y$.

For $25 <x<35$ integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $25$ to $x$; $35 <x<55$ integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $25$ to $55$; $55 <x<65$ integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $x-30$ to $x$. For $x \notin (25, 65)$ the density of $X+Y$ is $0$.   Once you find $f_{x+y}$ you can use $P(X+Y >50)=\int_{50}^{65} f_{x+y} (t)\, dt$.

Comment: so for this problem:

Comment: it will be $\int(0.1-0.00667(z-y)+1.1\times10^(-4)(z-y)^2*1/(35-25)$

Comment: @Abdula you have not specified the interval for $f_x$.  $f_x$ cannot  be a polynomial on the whole line. Such a function is not  a density function.

Comment: $fy = 1/b-a$ 

the interval $25<y<35$

the interval for $fx$

$0<x<30$

Trying to find the Pr(X+Y > 50)

Comment: @Abdula I have added more details. Now you have to carry put all the integrations.

Comment: $\int_0^{30} f_X(x)\mathrm d x\neq 1$.  The function is not a probability density function with that support.

Comment: @Abdula Graham Kemp is right. First fix your $f_x$ before you do any calculations.

Comment: @GrahamKemp You r right

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you said to integrate with respect to y but which one or should I integrate this one $int(fx(x-y)fydy$? if yes, I tried but actually I didn't understand why its $fx(x-y)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if you can explain the $fx(x-y)$ why x-y? I think it is z-y ?

Comment: If you integrate $f_x(x-y)f(y)$ you will get $f_{x+y (x)}$ and if you integrate $f_x(z-y)f(y)$ you will get $f_{x+y} (z)$.  Perhaps $z$ is a better symbol to use.